# Anaconda Python 3.4 using Seaborn figure too tight

Tags: matplotlib, hierarchical-clustering, seaborn, dendrogram

I am developing hierarchal clusters in the form of dendrograms using Python 3.4 and Seaborn, using the work of Olga Botvinnik (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/olgabot/bfe1e3638af3eea52fb1#). My goal is to cluster U.S. cities based on greenhouse gas emissions. I was able to successfully read my csv file and create a figure with residential and commercial buildings emissions on the x axis and city names on the y axis, but I cannot see any of the city names because they are too squished together. The image needs to be elongated so that I can read it. Can anyone point me in a good direction?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/JCMartel 1/Desktop/ghg_directory/rescom.csv', index_col=0)
data.index = data.index.map(lambda x: x.strip())

sns.clustermap(data);

#Need to improve layout
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.savefig('clustermap_bbox_tight.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to change, but `clustermap` takes a `figsize` parameter, ([examples here](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html)); maybe you could try changing that?

Comment: Is it too tight or too small? (I mean, you are passing `bbox_inches='tight` when you save the figure)

Comment: @mwaskom: Your solution worked. I used figsize=(7,30) and it stretched out the figure.

Comment: So if this is a working solution why don't you post it as the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the final script that I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/JCMartel 1/Desktop/ghg_directory/ghgmodel4.csv', index_col=0)
data.index = data.index.map(lambda x: x.strip())

cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True, rot=-.3, light=1)
sns.clustermap(data, col_cluster=False, cmap=cmap, linewidths=.5, figsize=(8, 30))
```